# Back Event Button on Android

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

If I wanted to catch the `Android` back event to decide if I could change my view how can I do it?
I try to add `MobileApplication.MobileEvent.BACK_BUTTON_PRESSED` on view but it is not `triggered`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302294/android-back-button-vs-desktop-escape-key/36308306#36308306, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336613/mobileapplication-mobileevent-back-button-pressed

Comment: Josè said:  
Yes, and no. Indeed, the event is not triggered on views, only on layers.... so how can i solve my problem?

Comment: Try to add an EventFilter to your scene like it is shown in the first link

Comment: ok, I try to add event to scene and now is ok.

Comment: I want to consume event and block it when switch previous view; Adding eventFilter I can intercept event after switch  to previous, instead I want to intercept before switch previous view

Comment: You have to use `scene.addEventFilter(handler)` instead of `scene.addEventHandler(handler)`. Then you will be able to consume the event