# How to prevent the Gluon App from closing on pressing Back

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I am creating a Gluon Glisten App with functionalities similar to an email client.
There is a login page as soon as the app is launched and on successful login a list of inbox items is displayed. How do I prevent the App from closing when the Back button on Android is pressed in the INBOX_VIEW. Is there a way to push the app to background when back is pressed in the last view on the stack?

Below are my three Views

```
  public static final  AppView LOGIN_VIEW = view("Login", LoginPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.HOME, HOME_VIEW,SKIP_VIEW_STACK);
    public static final AppView INBOX_VIEW = view("Inbox", InboxMessagesPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.MAIL, SHOW_IN_DRAWER,SKIP_VIEW_STACK);
    public static final AppView INBOX_MESSAGE_DETAIL_VIEW = view("InboxDetail", ReceivedMessageDetailPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.DASHBOARD);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336613/mobileapplication-mobileevent-back-button-pressed

Comment: The INBOX_VIEW is hidden on multiple instances not just hitting the back button in my app, example on going to the message detail . So is there any other way of detecting the BACK button in the app on the screen or overidding the stop of the application in Gluon

Comment: You can add an `EventFilter` to the scene containing vour INBOX_View, which listens for KeyCode.ESCAPE, like it is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302294/android-back-button-vs-desktop-escape-key/36308306#36308306